# Would anonymous Handler or Runnable create a memory leak?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

@Override
public void run() {
     // do stuff
}}, 100);
```

If I call this from an activity (onCreate or onResume or elsewhere) can this cause a memory leak? I've read that the `new Runnable()` should actually be  a static instance, is that true?

Comment: You have read that it should be a static *class.* An anonymous class cannot be static, ergo you should not use it in this way. But the issue is the non-static-ness, not the anonymity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This code may cause a memory leak.

For as long as this anonymous class based on `Runnable` is in the queue (100 milliseconds in this example), it keeps a reference to outer `Activity` class.

Such a memory leak is not a problem by itself of course, but depending on what code inside `run` is executed, it may create bigger problems, like crashing the application when you e.g. try to show dialog after `Activity` is killed. In such situations you will see nice informational exceptions:

> IllegalArgumentException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

or

> BadTokenException: Unable to add window - ... is your activity running?

Comment: I was going to post an answer along the same lines. Do you think that removing callbacks from the handler takes care of this concern?

Comment: @vikram Yes. I usually remove the `Runnable` in `onPause`.

Comment: Damn, We have these errors all over crashlytics.. :D

Comment: @MaciejGórski Hi I have a question that now the GC can handle the recursive dependence, so why this is a problem? Is it because  the runnable(a thread) is one of the root node?

Comment: @Jaskey Main Thread's `Looper` is defined as static, so it's a root holding `MessageQueue`, which holds all `Message`s and `Runnable`s until they are processed. Yes, there is something that keeps your `Activity` in memory and won't let it go until that `Runnable`'s `run` method finishes executing.

Comment: @MaciejGórski, my question is if the class is Foo(not Acitivity), we create a anonymous `Runable` running for 10 hours, and Foo is not referenced anymore, can the Foo instance be GCed before the runable task is done?

Comment: @Jaskey No. Foo instance will not be GCed. It's unreasonable however to create Runnable delayed with such a big value. Chances are it will never be executed as your app process is highly likely to be killed before.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is a leak. Because of the way Handlers work it is possible for them to stay alive for very long periods of time and prevent any resources they reference from being garbage collected. Here is a good explantion: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html

If your runnable may outlive the lifetime of your object, instead try the approach in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27825703/579234

What you are doing is adding another level of object on top of the usual case that would trigger the existing Lint warning about non-static handler classes will trigger a Lint warning: [Android lint checks](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks):

```
HandlerLeak
-----------
Summary: Ensures that Handler classes do not hold on to a reference to an
outer class

Priority: 4 / 10
Severity: Warning
Category: Performance

In Android, Handler classes should be static or leaks might occur. Messages
enqueued on the application thread's MessageQueue also retain their target
Handler. If the Handler is an inner class, its outer class will be retained as
well. To avoid leaking the outer class, declare the Handler as a static nested
class with a WeakReference to its outer class.
```

Using an anonymous class is the same thing as stated in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5:

> An anonymous class is always an inner class (§8.1.3); it is never static (§8.1.1, §8.5.1).

So, to explain explicitly, your runnable holds a reference to 'this' and the handler holds a reference to the runnable so 'this' won't be garbage collected until the handler is dead.